# Multiple access to direct ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I am currently creating application in java for real time audio communication. Plan is to handle multiple (over 100) simultaneous connections. One of the requirements is that I have to stream comfort noise when I get signal. What I am wondering is that in current implementation I for each connection I am loading file with noise to the memory and then I am pushing it to output in 20ms samples.

I am wondering if I am able to load it only once in memory. My first guess is to create `Enum Singleton` that will load file into direct `ByteBuffer` and then diffrent threads would access it and get diffrent samples.

Are there any drawbacks of this approach? Can I safely use multiple read only `ByteBuffers` referencing to the one created on the start? Will it work without problems in heavy loaded application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to `slice()` the buffer so that you get different views of it per thread, each with its own `position` and `limit`.

Comment: That is exactly what I am planning to do. I do not want to expose reference to this single ByteBuffer, I want to return read-only slices of it to the stream.